# Get characters after and before a pattern match in R

Tags: r, regex

Lets say I have a string in R:

```
str <- "abc abc cde cde"
```

and I use regmatches and gregexpr to find how many "b"´s there is in my string

```
regmatches(str, gregexpr("b",str))
```

but I want an output of everything that cointains the letter b.
So an output like: "abc", "abc".

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

```
tmp <- "abc abc cde cde"
```

### Split the string up into separate elements, grep for "b", return elements:

```
grep("b", unlist(strsplit(tmp, split = " ")), value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

Look for non-space before and after, something like:

```
regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\S*b\\S*", s))
# [[1]]
# [1] "abc" "abc"
```

Special regex characters are documented in [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html). For this case, `\\s` matches "any space-like character", and `\\S` is its negation, so any non-space-like character. You could be more specific, such as `\\w` ('word' character, same as `[[:alnum:]_]`). The `*` means zero-or-more, and `+` means one-or-more (forcing something).

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks Alot!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean you want to find *words* that contain `b`. One regex that does this is

```
\w*b\w*
```

`\w*` matches 0 or more word characters, which is a-z, A-Z, 0-9, and the underscore character.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CpTN1A/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R option using `strsplit` and `grepl`:

```
str <- "abc abc cde cde"
words <- strsplit(str, "\\s+")[[1]]
idx <- sapply(words, function(x) { grepl("b", x)})
matches <- words[idx]
matches

[1] "abc" "abc"
```